# How to get predicted values compared to actual values from a trained keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, predict

I have trained a model using keras based off of cryptocurrency prices. It trains well and has an accuracy of roughly 60%. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the results of model.predict() to compare/plot them with the actual values.

My model looks like this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation="tanh")) #could use relu
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    epochs=EPOCHS, 
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y))

# ## Plot predictions
targets = validation_data['close'] #get all the actual prices from the validation data
preds = model.predict(validation_x)
```

train_x is the first 90% or so of the data and validation_x is the last 10% or so.

targets returns as a Pandas Series that looks like:

```
time
1552021200    0.312
1552024800    0.312
1552028400    0.310
1552032000    0.311
1552035600    0.311
1552039200    0.311
1552042800    0.310
1552046400    0.309
1552050000    0.310
1552053600    0.312
```

but preds returns a ndarray that looks like:

```
[[0.41261673 0.5873832 ]
 [0.34726056 0.65273947]
 [0.33154735 0.6684527 ]
 ...
 [0.4990835  0.50091654]
 [0.27250433 0.7274957 ]
 [0.3717066  0.6282934 ]]
```

I've found so far that this ndarray is just the probabilities of each class, however I'm sure there is some way to use those probabilities to predict the values at the same index points as targets. Not sure how to do this though and having trouble finding out how.

Comment: Is it a classification problem or a regression problem?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal regression

Comment: If its regression, how can you use categorical cross entropy and a softmax function? Seems you have not chosen the right architecture.